# jQuery Datepicker add class to date if it's in array

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have a **jQuery Datepicker** where I want to add a class to a date if the date is in an array.

I have multiple arrays. A date will only be in one array or in no array, than it gets no extra class.

Here is my snippet, what is wrong below?

```js
var date_red = ["2020-10-27","2020-11-02","2020-11-07","2020-11-30","2021-05-26","2021-07-17",];
var date_green = ["2020-11-09","2020-11-16","2020-11-23","2020-11-24",];

$('.date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    prevText: "Eerder",
    nextText: "Later",
    minDate: null,
    firstDay: 1,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    dayNamesMin: [ "Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za" ],
    monthNames : [ "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ],
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        if( date_red.indexOf(string) != -1 ) {
            return [true, "red"]
        } else if( date_green.indexOf(string) != -1 ) {
            return [true, "green"]
        }
    }
});
```

When I run this code, it doesn't even show the calendar. When I replace the JavaScript with a variant where I only use one array, then the calendar works:

```js
var date_red = ["2020-10-27","2020-11-02","2020-11-07","2020-11-30","2021-05-26","2021-07-17",];

$('.date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    prevText: "Eerder",
    nextText: "Later",
    minDate: 0,
    firstDay: 1,
    dayNamesMin: [ "Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za" ],
    monthNames : [ "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ],
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ date_red.indexOf(string) != -1 ]
    }
});
```

The problem is in the if/else statement where I want to check both arrays and see in which one the current date is. What can I change to make the script work? I didn't find a similar working example here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer. I made one array with subarrays in it, every date has its own class name. In the jQuery Datepicker i made a function that checks the date:

`javascript`

```
var cssDates = [["11/7/2020", "green"],["11/9/2020", "green"],["11/16/2020", "yellow"],["11/23/2020", "red"],["11/24/2020", "green"],["11/30/2020", "yellow"],["5/26/2021", "red"],["7/17/2021", "red"]];

function SetDayStyle(date) {

    var enabled = true;
    var cssClass = "";
    var toolTip = "";

    var day = date.getDate();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; //0 - 11
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var compare = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    for (var i = 0; i < cssDates.length; i++) 
    {
        if (cssDates[i].indexOf(compare) >= 0) cssClass = cssDates[i][1];
    }

    return new Array(enabled, cssClass, toolTip);
}

$('.date').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    prevText: "Eerder",
    nextText: "Later",
    minDate: null,
    firstDay: 1,
    hideIfNoPrevNext: true,
    dayNamesMin: [ "Zo", "Ma", "Di", "Wo", "Do", "Vr", "Za" ],
    monthNames : [ "Januari", "Februari", "Maart", "April", "Mei", "Juni", "Juli", "Augustus", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ],
    beforeShowDay: SetDayStyle
});
```